# In a C while loop, is it possible to compare two variables, while (a < b)?

Tags: c, while-loop, comparison

In this piece of code, I am trying to have the user input an int value (x), and then have this value compared in the while loop below: while(k < x). My program crashes when I do this.

```
int main()
{
    long int sum = 0;
    long int i = 1;
    long int j = 2;
    long int k = 0;
    int x = 0;
    printf("This program will sum up all of the evenly valued terms from the 
    Fibionacci sequence, up until the\n user-specified highest term value.\n");
    printf("Set this limit: "); 
    scanf("%d",x);

while(k < x)
{   
    k = i + j;
    if(k%2==0)
        sum +=k;
    i = j;
    j = k;

}

printf("The sum of all of the evenly valued terms of the Fibionacci sequence up     until the value %d is %d",x,sum);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Certainly it's possible. What error message, if any, do you get when your program crashes?

Comment: You need `#include <stdio.h>` at the top of the program. Did you get any warnings from the compiler?

Comment: Please compile with warnings enabled. Your question title shows that you had been completely on the wrong track. The compiler is there to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program crashes because of this line:

```
scanf("%d",x);
```

C passes arguments by *value*, not by reference.  Consequently, for a C function to be able to modify a variable from the *caller*, the function expects a pointer, and the caller must pass the variable's address:

```
scanf("%d", &x);
```

By neglecting to pass the address, `scanf` attempts to write to some arbitrary location in memory (in this case, address 0), which results in undefined behavior.

Also see [Q12.12 from the comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/scanf1.html).

Answer (score 3):

Here you need an address:

```
scanf("%d",x); // ==> scanf("%d", &x);
```

otherwise strange things can happen. In C, when you are expecting to receive result in a function parameter you pass an address.

Comment: I was being pedantic.  It makes more sense to me to say you need the address of an integer (a pointer).

Comment: @squiguy: If you want to be pedantic, the word "pointer" is just fine. The C standard uses the unadorned word "pointer" to refer to an address value. See, for example, the description of `malloc()` in [http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf](N1570) 7.22.3.4.